# How to ignore "?" in a regular expression?

Tags: regex, iis

I've been using regular expressions in IIS to do a redirect so that if someone visits `/test01/` it will redirect them to `/test.asp?kw=test01`. However, I still want to be able to append a querystring, so that `/test01/src=url` would redirect to `/test.asp?kw=test01&src=url`.

This was easy enough to do, but what I would like is so that they could either use `/test01/src=url` OR `/test01/?src=url`, so the regex would be smart enough to ignore the question mark.

I've been using: `^test01/(.*)` to redirect to `/test.asp?kw=test01&{R:1}`. I have tried `^test01/(\??)(.*)` under the understanding that question marks allow the preceding character to be ignored, but that did not work, and I'm not exactly sure how to approach this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `test01/(*)` or `test01/?(*)` to `/test.asp?kw=test01&(*)`

Comment: What do you mean "that did not work"? Is it just that you forgot to change `{R:1}` to `{R:2}`? What output _did_ you get?

Comment: Well the page it redirects to uses the `src=url` part of the querystring I'm trying to append. With the question mark there, it redirects to `test.asp?kw=test01` correctly, but the `src=url` is left out. Without the question mark, everything works like I want it to, redirecting to `test.asp?kw=test01&src=url`. I'm trying to accept both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
^test01/\??(.*)
```

Otherwise, your `\??` is backreference #1, and your querystring becomes backreference #2.

---

**Update**

It also may be that you need to [disable back-tracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), using yet another meaning of `+`:

```
^test01/\??+(.*)
```

I don't know whether IIS supports this, though. And [PHP's engine doesn't seem to need it](http://www.ideone.com/wHvPI).

Comment: `^test01/\??+(.*)` comes up with the error "The expression "^test01/\??+(.*)" contains a repeat expression (one of '*', '?', '+', '{' in most contexts) that is not preceded by an expression."

Comment: @jblasco: Then your IIS does not support possessive quantifiers.

Comment: So do you think there is another way to simply get anything that comes after test01/, excluding a question mark, and set it as the `{R:1}`? Or I'll just have to write two specific rules for `/?src=` and `/src=` I guess.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be working now. Did you try my first example?

Comment: It redirects to the new page correctly, and works like I want without the question mark, redirecting from `/test01/src=url` to `/test.asp?kw=test01&src=url`. However, when I add in the question mark, the querystring does not work. Like, it redirects to `/test.asp?kw=test01`, but the rest of querystring is lost. Or, I don't know about "lost," because I can't actually see the URL, but they aren't applied on the page at least.

Comment: My suspicion is that it's maybe redirecting to `/test.asp?kw=test01&?src=url`?

Comment: Don't suspect. Find out. Look at logs. (I do not want to hear "does not work" one more time!)

Answer (score 0):

The following expression should work.

```
  ^test01/[?]?(.*)
```

Comment: This is precisely equivalent to what I wrote, except that you're using a redundant character class.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. The character class can be less confusing for some people as it doesn't require all the escapes.

Comment: OK; your answer also does not give an explanation.

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind when I am answering in the future.